# Squid 3.1.22 with multiple delaypools for different subnet

Tags: squid

i have a squid installed with squidguard. 
everything works great and now i want to implement a squid multi delay pool.

i want to separate webspeed for every subnet but have also one unlimited to special src

theory:

1) no speed limit to destination src XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX for all subnet 1/2/3

2) 300 kb web speed limit to subnet1

3) 100 kb web speed limit to subnet2

4) 200 kb web speed limit to subnet3

## my examples that works:

```
acl subnet1 src 10.10.0.0/24
acl subnet2 src 10.10.10.0/24
acl subnet3 src 10.10.30.0/24

delay_pools 3

delay_class 1 1
delay_access 1 allow subnet1
delay_access 1 deny all
delay_parameters 1  307200/307200

delay_class 2 1
delay_access 2 allow subnet2
delay_access 2 deny all
delay_parameters 1  102400/102400

delay_class 3 1
delay_access 3 allow subnet2
delay_access 3 deny all
delay_parameters 3  204800/204800
```

The next step is to create a delaypool to a specified destinations WITHOUT a speed limit for subnet1 & subnet2 & subnet 3 !

## examples that i need:

```
delay_pools 4

acl nolimittodestination src xxx.xxx.xxx
acl subnet1 src 10.10.0.0/24
acl subnet2 src 10.10.10.0/24
acl subnet3 src 10.10.30.0/24

delay_class 1 ?
delay_access nolimittodestination ?
delay_access 1 subnet1
delay_access 1 subnet2    
delay_access 1 deny all
delay_parameters 1  ?     #


delay_class 1 1
delay_access 1 allow subnet1
delay_access 1 deny all
delay_parameters 1  307200/307200

delay_class 2 1
delay_access 2 allow subnet2
delay_access 2 deny all
delay_parameters 1  102400/102400

delay_class 3 1
delay_access 3 allow subnet2
delay_access 3 deny all
delay_parameters 3  204800/204800
```

Anyone an idea like this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

For ACL's which you wish to deliver at full-speed, simply put an http_access allow statement above your delay pools, e.g.:

http_access allow localnet nolimittodestination

Squid processes the rules specified in your squid.conf in a linear fashion, so that explicit allow statements at the top of the file will be processed before the delay pools statement.